# Default Percentage Value

Tags: error-messages, percent

I am trying to set a default value in a percent field where the final output is 5%.  When I set the default value as 5, the UI shows 500%.  However when I try to set the default value as .05 I receive a syntax error.  What am I doing wrong?

Error: Syntax error. Found '.'
Use formula syntax: Enclose text and picklist value API names in double quotes : ("the_text"), include numbers without quotes : (25), show percentages as decimals: (0.10), and express date calculations in the standard format: (Today() + 7), To reference a field from a Custom Metadata type record use: $CustomMetadata.Type__mdt.RecordAPIName.Field__c
Percent Options

Answer (score 1):

You must include a leading zero, as in `0.05`.

Comment: So simple.  Thank you!